# Broadcasting and resizing an array in dask

Tags: numpy, dask, python-xarray, python-3.9

I want to broadcast a 1D dask array and a 2D dask array.

To be specific using numpy it would be something like:

```
a = np.random.rand(20000, 3)
b = np.random.rand(16)
```

I want a 3D array of size (20000,16,3) as result, let's call it `c`. So for each value of `b` we will have (20000,3) values multiplying `a*b[index]`, where `index=0,1,...,15`. In numpy it's pretty straightforward using function resize. However, resize does not exist in dask. Anyone has any idea of how I do this on dask? The array can also be xarray with dask array inside, so if anyone knows how to do it with xarray it will be appreciated as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to achieve this result

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(20000, 3)
b = np.random.rand(16)

result = a[:, np.newaxis, :] * b[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
result.shape  # (20000, 16, 3)
```

That code directly works for a `dask.array` as well

```py
import dask.array as da

dsk_a = da.from_array(a)
dsk_b = da.from_array(b)

result_dask = dsk_a[:, np.newaxis, :] * dsk_b[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]

result_dask.shape  # (20000, 16, 3)
(result_dask.compute() == result).all()  # True
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question. If I have, then it would be helpful if you provide a working `numpy` code that provides the desired result.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, it's what I was looking for. Although I think that doing `dsk_a[:, np.newaxis, :]` has a similar effect than doing `dsk_a_broadcast = da.tile(dsk_a, 16).reshape((len(a), 16, 3))` right?

Comment: @MiguelCárcamo the `np.newaxis` method is the same as calling `dsk_a.reshape((len(a), 16, 3))`: they both simply add a dimension in the middle (shape `(20000, 1, 3)`). The array then gets [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The important difference from tiling is that you never need to allocate 16-times the memory for the intermediate array!